# Image styles thumbnail, medium, large to default dimenssions

Tags: media

My drupal create thumbnail of my uploaded image (thumbnail, medium and large). 
I don't want to have redimensioned images, I want original size.

PS: drupal create 3 images per uploaded image, so, for me are lots of nodes.

How can I stop drupal from creating these?

Comment: Please don't [cross post questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484877/drupal-image-styles-thumbnail-medium-large-to-default-dimenssions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Configuration -> Media -> Image Styles (or analogous path in non-7 versions). By default you have 3 styles there, the ones you mentioned. You can edit them to suit your needs, but deleting them is not supported - to many modules uses them.

On the other hand, styled image files are supposed to be created on first access. You shouldn't have them on your file system until something really needs them, so to get rid of those files simply turn off everything that uses them, and purge `/sites/*/files/styles` directory.