# Is every image style I have for each image upload auto-created?

Tags: 8, media

I believe I understand this about Drupal 8: every image uploaded will automatically be created in each of the image styles I have set up (or the default 3 that come with core).

This incentivizes me NOT to create very many image styles, because then I'll end up with a bunch of different copies of my original image, whether they will ever be used in that particular style or not.

Is that correct?

On the other hand, Molot's answer [over here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78425/image-styles-thumbnail-medium-large-to-default-dimenssions?rq=1) mentions that "styled image files are supposed to be created on first access". That gives me hope that if I upload an image, it will only be created in an image style the first time it is requested in that image style. That means I could have as many custom image styles as I need and not worry that an image will be created for each one of those every time.

For example, if I have 12 custom image styles, but I only call a certain image in one style, will I end up with only 2 copies of the image, one as the original upload and one in the only style I called? This is what I would love to be true.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: `I only call a certain image in one style, will I end up with only 2 copies of the image, one as the original upload and one in the only style I called?` Yes.

Comment: They are saved in the `/sites/default/files/styles` folder, in case you are wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The styled images will be created on first request, creating a new file with the styled image. This will not only save space if you have tons of image styles but also CPU power - because if you attach 10 images to a node and want to create 12 (as you mention the number) different image styles, that will put quite a load to generate all the styled images in one go. Doing this when needed is far better management of resources.

Comment: To make sure I understand, the first time I call an image it creates the image style needed on that page and NO other? Or the first time I call an image, it creates all the image styles I ever specified?

Comment: If you go to a page that you defined to show an image with style A, then only the file that corresponds to that style A will be created, no others.